# echo specific string/text along with a particular username in php

Tags: php

I have a table, call *posts* like this:

```
post_id       topic_id       user_id     content         date
   1               7            12         bla bla         7/15/2014
   2               16           70         bla bla         7/16/2014
   3               7            14         bloa bla        7/20/2014
```

Assume that I have other two tables called *users* that has the `user_id` and `username` columns, and the *topics* table which is linked to the *posts* table by the foreign key called `topic_id` . The `user_id` in the *posts* table is the foreign key of the *users* table.

Assume that I can echo all the columns in the *posts* table successfully.

As you can see in the *posts* table, the `topic_id # 7` has two (and probably many more) post_id # **1** and **3**, which would be added by any other `user_ids` associated with any other `usernames`.

However, my problem is that I am ONLY able to echo the string/text `Posted By username` for all `usernames` that are associated with the particular *topic_id*, i.e., # 7. Now, what i want and am struggling is to **echo** the first `username` (of course from the *users* table) who added the `post_id` # 1 along with **the string/ text** like *Posted By* which is output like `Posted By username1` (user_id #12); and the `post_id` # 3 along with another *string/text* like *Replied By* which is output like `Replied By usename2` (user_id #14).

Note: This is my query:

```
$q = "SELECT post_id, content, date, username 
      FROM posts 
      INNER JOIN users USING (user_id)";

$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q)

while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    echo "<p>Posted By {$row['username']} ({$row['date']})<br />{$row['content']}</p><br />\n";


}
```

Your help will be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Sorry but I am having difficulty understanding what is it that you want... So you wish to echo out the first row from posts with the user's username?Thats all ?

Comment: sorry for being unclear, but i want to echo out the first `username` of the first `post_id` for the particular `topic_id`, i.e., # 7, as `Posted By username1`, and the other `post_id` for the same particular `topic_id` , i.e., # 7, as `Replied by username2` onward. I mean with the same topic and different replies, I wish to have different text/strings echo'ed along with the 2nd username from the 1st username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I am updateing Perry's post a bit I think I understand what you wish to do here it is

You need to order it by topics and then posts so the one who created the post gets to be first

```
$q = "SELECT p.post_id, p.content, p.date, u.username ,p.topic_id
  FROM posts p JOIN users u on (u.user_id=p.user_id)
  ORDER BY p.topic_id, p.post_id
";
```

Now in your while loop you need to do something like this we also need to keep track which topics were already displayed so we will need a empty array for this.

```
    $displayedTopics = array();

        while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            if (!in_array($row['topic_id'],$displayedTopics))
            {
             echo "<p>Posted By {$row['username']} ({$row['date']})<br />{$row['content']}</p><br />\n"; // We echo out from who it was posted
             // Then add it to the displayed array
            $displayedTopics[] = $row['topic_id'];
            }

 // Otherwise we just echo out as it was a reply
             else
               echo "<p>Replied By {$row['username']} ({$row['date']})<br />{$row['content']}</p><br />\n";


     }
```

Hope this helps and I understood what you wish to accomplish!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$q = "SELECT p.post_id, p.content, p.date, u.username 
  FROM posts p JOIN users u on (u.user_id=p.user_id)";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what I wish is the different text/string to be printed out for the first `username` from the one for the 2nd username onward. For example, `Post By eric`, `Replied By Adam`. the names `Eric` and `Adam` are the two usernames that created the topic and the repli(es).